Snake drawn twice
When I exit the game and re-enter it quickly the snake is drawn twice or 3 times if you go in and out quick enough.
I have tried to delete the snake in various places but it has not removed it when I re-enter the game quickly.
As I read through the code it all seems to make sense but it doesn't work
This is my first game and I'm sure I've just missed something simple
from tkinter import *
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SPACE_SIZE = 25
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOUR = "#00A86B"
FOOD_COLOUR = "#DC143C"
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "#2C3E50"
TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 48, "bold")
BUTTON_FONT = ("Helvetica", 24)
TEXT_COLOR = "#ECF0F1"

speed = 100
mode_ = "Medium"
in_game = False  
in_start_screen = True  

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOUR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)

class Food:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]
        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOUR, tag="food")

def next_turn(snake, food):
    global direction, score

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOUR)
    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.coordinates[0] and y == food.coordinates[1]:
        score += 1
        label.config(text=f"Score: {score}")

        canvas.delete("food")
        food = Food()

        if mode_ == "Dynamic":
            global speed
            speed = max(10, speed - 5)

    else:
        del snake.coordinates[-1]
        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])
        del snake.squares[-1]

    if check_collisions(snake):
        game_over()
    else:
        window.after(speed, next_turn, snake, food)

def change_direction(new_direction):
    global direction

    if new_direction == "left" and direction != "right":
        direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "right" and direction != "left":
        direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "up" and direction != "down":
        direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "down" and direction != "up":
        direction = new_direction

def check_collisions(snake):
    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0 or x >= GAME_WIDTH or y < 0 or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True

    return False

def game_over():
    global in_game, in_start_screen

    in_game = False
    in_start_screen = False  

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 2,
                       font=("Helvetica", 50, "bold"), text="GAME OVER", fill=FOOD_COLOUR, tag="gameover")
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 1.5,
                       font=("Helvetica", 20), text="\nPress SPACE to try again.\nPress ESC to return to the home screen.", fill=FOOD_COLOUR, tag="gameover")
    window.bind("<space>", lambda event: start_game())
    window.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: go_to_start_screen())

def start_game():
    global score, direction, food, snake, label, canvas, in_game, in_start_screen

    in_game = True
    in_start_screen = False  

    canvas.delete("snake")
    canvas.delete("food")
    canvas.pack_forget() 
    if label:
        label.destroy()
    if start_button:
        start_button.destroy()
    if title_label:
        title_label.destroy()
    if easy_button:
        easy_button.destroy()
    if medium_button:
        medium_button.destroy()
    if hard_button:
        hard_button.destroy()
    if dynamic_button:
        dynamic_button.destroy()

    canvas.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor="n")  

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    label = Label(window, text="Score: 0", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, width=23)
    label.pack(pady=10)
    score = 0
    direction = "down"
    label.config(text=f"Score: {score}")

    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    next_turn(snake, food)

    window.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: go_to_start_screen())

def start_screen():
    global start_button, title_label, easy_button, medium_button, hard_button, canvas, window, button_style, in_game, in_start_screen, dynamic_button

    in_game = False
    in_start_screen = True

    canvas.pack_forget()  
    canvas.delete(ALL)

    window.geometry(f"{GAME_WIDTH}x{GAME_HEIGHT + 100}") 
    window.configure(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR)  

    title_label = Label(window, text="Snake Game", font=TITLE_FONT, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, fg=TEXT_COLOR)
    title_label.pack(pady=(40, 20)) 

    button_style = {
        'font': ("Helvetica", 20),  
        'bg': "#2980B9",  
        'fg': TEXT_COLOR,
        'activebackground': "#3498DB",  
        'activeforeground': TEXT_COLOR,
        'bd': 0, 
        'width': 18,
        'height': 2,
        'cursor': 'hand2'  
    }

    start_button = Button(window, text=f"Start Game\n({mode_})", **button_style, command=start_game)
    easy_button = Button(window, text="Easy", **button_style, command=lambda: update_mode("easy"))
    medium_button = Button(window, text="Medium", **button_style, command=lambda: update_mode("medium"))
    hard_button = Button(window, text="Hard", **button_style, command=lambda: update_mode("hard"))
    dynamic_button = Button(window, text="Dynamic", **button_style, command=lambda: update_mode("dynamic"))

    easy_button.pack(pady=10)
    medium_button.pack(pady=10)
    hard_button.pack(pady=10)
    dynamic_button.pack(pady=10)
    start_button.pack(pady=(20, 10))

    window.unbind("<Escape>")

def update_mode(selected_mode):
    global speed, mode_, start_button

    if selected_mode == "easy":
        speed = 100
        mode_ = "Easy"
    elif selected_mode == "medium":
        speed = 75
        mode_ = "Medium"
    elif selected_mode == "hard":
        speed = 50
        mode_ = "Hard"
    elif selected_mode == "dynamic":
        speed = 100
        mode_ = "Dynamic"

    start_button.config(text=f"Start Game\n({mode_})")

def go_to_start_screen():
    global canvas, in_game, in_start_screen

    if in_game or not in_start_screen:
        canvas.pack_forget()
        canvas.delete(ALL)
        canvas.delete("snake")
        canvas.delete("food")
        label.destroy()

        start_screen()

window = Tk()
window.title("Snake Game")

label = Label(window, text="", bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)

window.bind("<Left>", lambda event: change_direction("left"))
window.bind("<Right>", lambda event: change_direction("right"))
window.bind("<Up>", lambda event: change_direction("up"))
window.bind("<Down>", lambda event: change_direction("down"))
window.bind("<a>", lambda event: change_direction("left"))
window.bind("<d>", lambda event: change_direction("right"))
window.bind("<w>", lambda event: change_direction("up"))
window.bind("<s>", lambda event: change_direction("down"))

start_screen()

window.mainloop()


Your code fails with error in line 35  when you do random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer  you need to fix this first by casting the division into an int

Then I would recommand putting all your game inside a Game class that you can instantiate. When you exit the game just deinstantiate the Game and when you start a new game create a new instance. You are using globals everywhere, which persist when you start a new game. Use classes and instances and get rid of all those glabal variables.

Your code is working. I set speed = 2.. Your snake is already moved. I don't see no issue so far

Add double slash for both x and y.  x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE
y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT // SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE

I don't see nothing wrong. I see that you did https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-game-using-tkinter-python/. But I was looking at start_game function.

It is because whenever next_turn(...) is executed, a new after loop will be created which create another snake.
You need to cancel the current after loop before starting new game.  So you need to save the ID of the after loop (returned by .after()) and cancel it using .after_cancel():
...

def next_turn(snake, food):
   ...

   else:
       # save the after ID using an attribute of window
       window.after_id = window.after(speed, next_turn, snake, food)

...

def go_to_start_screen():
    ...

    if in_game or not in_start_screen:
        ...
        # cancel current after loop before go to start screen
        window.after_cancel(window.after_id)
        start_screen()

...


On line 71:  name speed is used for prior to global destination. If I went back to OP's script, it would work.

If I comment out #window.after_id = window.after(speed, next_turn, snake, food). will work.
